# jquery and javascript: two load functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys,
quick question: is it actually possible and semantic to use two `$(window).load(function(e){` functions on one website?

e.g. i have a header.php which holds a `<script>` tag with some jquery - `$(window).load(function(e){` is part of it. underneath it i have another  tag that links to an external .js file that has the again a `$(window).load(function(e){`.

is this allowed and ok?

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Every `load()` declaration you make will simply be appended to the existing handler.

From the [docs on `.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) (which is the function that handles the actual work for the `load()` shortcut):

> When an event reaches an element, all handlers bound to that event type for the element are fired. If there are multiple handlers registered, they will always execute in the order in which they were bound. After all handlers have executed, the event continues along the normal event propagation path.

Answer (score 1):

The `.load()` function (and other event-related functions) accepts a function that it places in the event handler queue when the event fires.

So, to more directly answer your question, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Lets just talked about how is it possible?

Suppose, you have more than one events which you want to call on when your page completely loaded. Lets examine this in `JavaScript` to get more about the concept and keep it simple to easy to understand.

```
var pageLoadEvents = [];
```

We have created an array where we will keep all our event which we want to call when page loaded.

```
pageLoadEvents.push( function() {
  alert("hello!");
} )
```

And:

```
pageLoadEvents.push( function() {
  alert("How are you doing?");
} )
```

Now, you have defined all your events that you would like to raise on page load and all of them are in a `pageLoadEvents` array. Here, we write our final piece:

```
window.onload = function() {
 for(var index=0; index<pageLoadEvents.length; index++) {
   pageLoadEvents[index]();
 }
}
```

All events that we keep in `pageLoadEvents` array will be executed one by one.

Every time you call a `load` on `$(window)` it keep the content (e.g function(e) { .. }) you defined in `load` in an array and finally execute them each of them.